# Magento 2: CSS is not loading only in admin menu

Tags: magento2, admin, menu

I am having some strange issues. Css is not loading only for the menu in admin side. Apart from that, everything is working fine.
All js and css are unmerged

[image]

Page source

[image: Page source]

I've tried these commands

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

Comment: Any browser console errors?

Comment: Try this command: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f de_DE

Comment: @RajMohanR no. we dont get any

Comment: @ChandraPrakashGupta yes we already did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put magento's default styles.css in `pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/` folder and check it.

Is it Working or Not? If it is working then please check Magento's core file. `vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/css`

Might be there is someone changed.

Comment: thanks, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many reasons that CSS & JavaScript are not loading. Follow the below steps; it might help to solve your problem.

1. Set the proper permissions and ownership. You should set the proper filesystem permissions and ownership: [File system permissions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/file-system-perms.html)
2. Deploy the static content (remove `pub/static` & `var, generated` folder then run s:s:d command)
3. Ensure you have not missed the .htaccess files: [What .htaccess files does Magento 2 use?](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/760)
4. The problem could be caused by a lack of memory for the Less compiler. [How to fix](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/3868)

I hope it helps!

Comment: I did everything you said, still not working